# What criteria can I use in MS Access to have monthly sales data appear only if it is between specified start and end dates?

Tags: ms-access

I am using MS Access 2013.

The query I am working on is called "Bookings Query." Within the Bookings Query, I have two tables (Initialization and Bookings) joined together by Assignment Code. The Initialization table contains data for Sales Reps and their assignments with start/end dates and the Bookings table contains data for assignments and their monthly quota.

I need to have monthly quota data from the Bookings table only appear if it's within the Start and End Dates which come from the Initialization table. For Example: if we look at Assignment "ABC", and quota is $150,000 for January but the start and end dates for "ABC" are 2/1/21 - 12/31/21, then I need January to be $0 since quota for this assignment does not start until February.

Thanks in advance. It's a bit confusing I know.

Comment: make sure to tell access the tables are linked.  In the query designer you should see a line between assignmentcode in the initialization table and assignmentcode in the bookings table..  In these cases, you usually make a parameterized query.  For instance in the current row under StartDate you put: > parameter1 and under EndDate you put < parameter2.  Take a look at this older example: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-parameters-in-queries-forms-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356

Comment: Edit question to show sample raw data and desired output as text tables. Why would January have a quota of $150,000 - is this amount for multiple assignments not just for ABC?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample I have used regularly

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Accounts.AccountNumber, Accounts.AccountName, Sum(Transactions.[DEBIT AMOUNT]) AS DEBIT, Sum(Transactions.[CREDIT AMOUNT]) AS CREDIT
FROM Accounts LEFT JOIN Transactions ON Accounts.AccountID = Transactions.AccountID
WHERE (((Transactions.TransactionDate)>=[forms]![Report Date Range]![Beginning Rpt Date] And (Transactions.TransactionDate)<=[Forms]![Report Date Range]![Ending Rpt Date]))
```

Comment: I suspect this is not what OP is looking for. Appears they want data organized by From and To dates in a table, not filtered by user inputs on form.